# Changing QueryDSL Generated Files Directory

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I have integrated QueryDSL into my Spring boot project.

build.gradle:

```
//dependencies
compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.7.4")
compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.7.4:jpa")

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('src/main/generated/')
        generatedSourceDirs += file('src/main/generated/')
    }
}
```

The generated `.class` and `.java` (Q classes) files are currently deployed into `build/classes/main/my/package/model` where the entity class files are created.

How can I configure the `JPAAnnotationProcessor` to put generated sources(e.g. QMyEntity.java) into `src/main/generated`?

Answer (score 1):

#### You could try something like that (hard way):

```
def queryDslOutput = file("src/main/generated")
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir queryDslOutput
        }
    }
}

task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.compile
    destinationDir = queryDslOutput
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", 'com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor,lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor'
    ]
}
compileJava.dependsOn(generateQueryDSL)

clean {
    delete queryDslOutput
}
```

The compiler options are required if you are using lombok.

#### Or if you are using the [querydsl-plugin](https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/tree/master/querydsl-plugin) you could configure the output directory (easy way):

```
def generatedClassesPath= "build/generated/source/querydsl/main"

querydsl {
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = generatedClassesPath
}
```

You could always add generated sources to classpath to catch the files by Intellij Idea:

```
def queryDslOutput = file(generatedClassesPath)
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir queryDslOutput
        }
    }
}
```

From plugin documentation:

> `querydslSourcesDir`
>
> The project relative path to where the querydsl
>   meta model sources are created in. It does not matter which annotation
>   processors are used, all meta model classes will be created within
>   this directory.
>
> Defaults to `src/querydsl/java`.